# Is there such a thing as a comment in IL?

Tags: .net, syntax, comments, cil, il

I realize nobody just sits down and develops software in straight IL (do they?). But suppose you want to share a snippet of IL code (as output by, e.g., the C# compiler) with someone else for discussion, and furthermore you want to annotate it with a few comments. Is there an actual syntax for comments in IL so that you could do this without making the text invalid as IL? Not really a big deal, just curious.

Comment: I have developed in straight IL, but only because I was building a .net compiler.  So yeah, it's more than a little uncommon.  8 )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use `//` and `/* ... */` just like in C#.

I can't find any reference to it in ECMA-335, but this [IL guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3778/Introduction-to-IL-Assembly-Language) includes:

> The first two lines (started with `//`) are the comments. In ILAsm, you can comment in the same way as that in C# or C++. To comment multiple lines or the part of line, you can also use `/* ... */` block as well.

Comment: Ha, not what I would have expected, but perfectly logical nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft has its own version of the ecma doc, much more extensive.  MSIL is described here: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2FD%2FC%2F1%2FDC1B219F-3B11-4A05-9DA3-2D0F98B20917%2FPartition%2520VI%2520-%2520Annexes.doc&rct=j&q=site%3Adownload.microsoft.com%20partition%20vi&ei=JW0nTfO5CpGlnQe1psmMAQ&usg=AFQjCNHHTRslrgzeSkbPEpCcb5i9rBTsfA&cad=rja

Answer (score 2):

you use // in IL for comments as well...